# SoundEffect.Play() threading considerations

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm trying to understand the threading and queuing model when used SoundEffect.Play() so that I can play notes with accurate timing.

Is the sound played back synchronously on the UI thread? Or is a background thread used to play the samples at the correct time?

I've read that I need to call FrameworkDispatcher.Update() for the sounds to play, but what is this doing?

Is there a queue for the sounds? What if I call play on a SoundEffect that is already playing. Will another instance be started in parallel, or will the current stop first?

As for sequencing sounds I assume the best approach is to use a background thread and Thread.Sleep() to make sure I wake up at the correct time to play the next "note". Or is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

SoundEffects play Asynchronously. That's why you can have lots of them playing at once.

Assuming that you're creating an app in Silverlight, `FrameworkDispatcher.Update()` must be called (typically 20 times a second) because `SoundEffect` is from the XNA framework and is expecting an underlying game loop as part of it's execution model. Repeated calls to `FrameworkDispatcher.Update()` simulate this.

Setting up calls to this in an `ApplicationLifeObject` is the way this is most typically done.

In terms of sequencing sounds, I'd use a timer and trigger new sounds to play that way rather than have lots of calls to `Thread.Sleep`.